# Problem with text messaging on new xs iphone with shared itunes account

Tags: iphone

We just recently got the new iphone xs.  We have a shared account with several devices.  For some reason, when I text my daughter it goes to my husband or vice versa.  The same thing happens when my husband or daughter try to text each other, it comes to my phone and not theirs.  My husband has tried to update every setting but it's very frustrating.  Any thoughts?  I know it's been mentioned setting up separate iTunes accounts for each person, but would it allow us to share already purchased or downloaded music because we have hundreds of songs.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!  Thanks. AJ

Comment: grg has a good solution. Also note if you are sending messages to an Apple ID via email address instead of a unique email or phone number it will go to any device associated with that Apple ID email.

Answer (score 1):

You can have separate Apple IDs for Messages and FaceTime while keeping the same Apple ID for iTunes & App Store. Create an Apple ID for each person, then log into this Apple ID in Settings under Messages and FaceTime, leaving the existing Apple ID for iTunes and App Store purchases.

Comment: We are sending the text to the their cell phone number which we have on the account.  It's just very strange as we never had this problem with our previous ones.  Thanks for the info on creating the Apple ID for each specifically for the text msgs and FT.  We were just worried we wouldn't have access to the iTunes playlist we have stored.  

When we do that will we have to reset anything with the new id's or just go into settings and add the new apple id?

Comment: Settings > Messages > Text Message Forwarding is likely the setting that’s different.  FWIW, appleIds are meant to be used per user, from there add Family Sharing to share resources. (Which isn’t actually a perfect solution if any device in the mix is shared between users).